# numpy, replace column with array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to replace one or several columns with a new array with the same length.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[0,0,0])
a[:, 0] = b
```

I got an error of `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)`. However this works when b has multiple columns.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[0,7],[0,7],[0,7]])
a[:, 0:2] = b

array([[0, 7, 3],
       [0, 7, 3],
       [0, 7, 3]])
```

How can I efficiently replace a column with another array?

Thanks

J

Comment: Supply flattened version - `a[:, 0] = b.ravel()` or with `b[:,0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect shape of `b`. You should pass an ordinary 1D array to it if you want to replace only one column:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([0,0,0])
a[:, 0] = b
a
```

Returns:

```
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example will work fine if you use the following just like you are using `a[:, 0:2] = b`. `[:, 0:1]` is effectively just the first column

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[0],[0],[0]])
a[:, 0:1] = b

# array([[0, 2, 3],
#        [0, 2, 3],
#        [0, 2, 3]])
```